# SugarCRM: ImageField upload size restriction

Tags: sugarcrm

How can Imagesize be restricted while using/uploading sugar's ImageField? My guess is there should be any property of field. I want that user upload maximum 2MB image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the POST_MAX_FILE size form field to the form and it should apply that restriction...

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: thank's @jmertic this is manual solution, as now I need to code manually to show warnings which images are not uploaded. There should be anything implemented in the sugar as they provided imageFields. However i accepted the answer. :)

Comment: I agree with you; perhaps you could add a bug for this at http://bugs.sugarcrm.com? Thanks!

Comment: reported the issue here [bugs.sugarcrm.com](http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html#issue_57713).

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration setting `upload_maxsize` in `config.php`. But this limit will be applied to all uploads and not just for the image field.

Comment: yeah, I only have to apply limit on image fields,